# change event that isn't deferred until focus lost

Tags: jquery

According to the [JQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/change/), the `change` for text fields only fire when focus is lost:

> For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but **for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus**.

Is there an event that doesn't have this focus lost requirement?

I want the event to fire whenever a text field has visibly changed, accounting for the various ways it might change (keyboard, mouse copy-and-paste, etc.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recomment binding the `input` event along with `keyup` to support older browsers.

```
$('input').on('input keyup', function(e) {
    // Do stuff
});
```

Comment: "input event"?  Where is that documented?

Comment: Perfect.  I couldn't find this documented anywhere in the JQuery API.  Not only does that handle mouse and keyboard changes, but saves me from binding my function to multiple events (except in the case of supporting older browsers w/ `keyup`).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

onkeyup for keyboard, and onclick for mouse might do the trick. It might be best still to leave an onchange , "just in case".

Comment: Sorry, onkeydown might be more appropriate.

Comment: Why? For instance if you press and hold a key, onkeydown is triggered once, and you don't know yet how many characters will be generated. onkeypress will be triggered for each character, and onkeyup after the key is no longer pressed, making it a good candidate.

Comment: @ori I thought onkeypress would only be triggered once when continuously pressing a key...